# Could not get data from services in android but works fine in web browser on desktop

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to get the data from firebase in my services in android when I run ionic capacitor run android but I keep getting undefined. However, I can get the data just fine on web browser when I run ionic serve. Can anyone please enlighten me on that? I have been struggling with this for days.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I have an angular app which uses firebase and used capacitor to make an android app and it never gave me issues.  Here is my notes I follow when I made it.  Did you miss anything below??:

Run this in your terminal:
npm install --save @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli

then run this command:
npx cap init

Notes:
make sure outputPath in the angular.json file matches the webDir in the capacitor.config.json file.  I set them both to "www".  And also make sure in capacitor.config.json file, bundledWebRuntime = “false”.

ng build --prod

npx cap serve  (which you said it was working at this point, so I assume everything to this point is ok)

then run these 3 commands in your terminal:

npx cap add android

npx cap copy android

npx cap open android